# How to add new comment in wp-api using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, wp-api

I want to add new comment to wordpress's post in WP-API using angular js. And this is my function to do that:

```
WPService.setComment = function(comment) {
    var data = [
        {
            'author_email'  : comment.email,
            'author_name'   : comment.name,
            'author_url'    : comment.url,
            'content'       : comment.body,
            'post'          : comment.post
        }
    ];
    return $http.post('wp-json/wp/v2/comments', data[0]).success(function(res, status, header) {
        console.log('comment posted...!');
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. How can I add new comment in this way?

**UPD #1** It seems angular can't enter to error block and return errors before that. These are errors:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at Object.parse (native)
at fromJson (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:1271:14)
at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:9460:16)
at http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:9551:12
at forEach (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:340:20)
at transformData (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:9550:3)
at transformResponse (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:10319:21)
at processQueue (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:14792:28)
at http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:14808:27
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/bower_components/angular/angular.js?ver=4.4.2:16052:28)
```

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: I guess your `wp-api` code is not returning a proper response..

Comment: I think you right. Because I commented out parameters one by one and I get the errors just when I send `post` parameter. I think I should to report this on github project.

Comment: Now I find that the comment submitted properly, But angular get that error. Why?

Comment: Because on call you normally get a response back.. Seems like that response is not in correct format..  Can you share your comment api code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [WP-API's github issues page](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2260), This was a bug which will be resolve in version 2.0 beta 13.
For temporary solution before next beta release we can apply the [80dcacf](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/commit/80dcacf95140a445d262aefb55d1054ee2750108) commit on `class-wp-rest-comments-controller.php` file of the plugin.